# Does anyone know how to build dpdk on buildroot (generated system)

Tags: buildroot, dpdk

trying to build an x86_64 dpdk on a buildroot generated file system ..
any guide ...
i searched thoughtlessly on the internet before asking for couple of days with no avail 
Best Regards
rama

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate question for StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the package to buildroot. Fortunately, [a patch was posted recently that adds it](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/554675/). Just apply that patch to your buildroot source.